# Doesn't bind DateTime property for model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, datetimepicker

In my mvc 4 project in some model I've `DateTime` property. On client side I use `jquery datepicker`. I want to have format as 'dd.mm.yyyy'. I set attribute for property

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "* Field is required")]
    public DateTime DateBuy { get; set; }
```

In *.js file I set date format to:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,

    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

and also I ovverided jquery validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    'date',
    function (value, element, params) {
        return value.match(/^\d\d?\.\d\d?\.\d\d\d\d$/);
    },
    ''
);
```

But when model came to action model is not valid. Error: `"The value '24.02.2013' is not valid for DateBuy."`

If date will be as `02.24.2013` all work good (Server expect date in format 'mm.dd.yyyy'). I tried change culture in `web.config`:

```
<globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-RU" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GET or POST verb on submitting the value to your action?
If you are using GET then datetime value shoulf be ALWAYS in invariant culture format.

If you are using POST than web.config globalization setting should be enough to accept the date string in desired format.

Comment: I using POST. I added globalization tag in web.config, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: can you share the view and controller code? You are using <globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-RU" enableClientBasedCulture="true" /> enableClientBasedCulture is true, make it false or configure your browser to use russians culture